# jQuery drop menu will not open in Explorer - how to fix this?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I had to make some adjustments to my script to allow the Sprytabs to function within this dropdown menu. Everything is working perfectly for me in FF and Chrome , however I'm using IE9 also, and the menu will not even open. However if i open webdeveloper tools in IE, the menu begins to work fine, but on new load of browser will not open again. I don't know if this is a focus issue in IE with the script? Any help would be appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/7aSDS/53/

```
$(function(){

       $('#navigation_horiz ul li').bind('mouseenter',function(e){
        $('#navigation_horiz ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if($(this).children('.dropdown').length>0){
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').attr('id',$(this).children('.dropdown').attr('id'));            

            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').html($(this).children('.dropdown').html());
                        console.log($('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').html());
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').slideDown(500);
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().css('opacity',0);
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().animate({opacity:0},0).animate({opacity:1},1000,'linear');
        }
    });

    jQuery.expr[':'].focus = function( elem ) {
      return elem === document.activeElement && ( elem.type || elem.href );
    };  

    $('#navigation_horiz').bind('mouseleave',function(){
        if($('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').children().length > 0 && $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').attr('id')=='dropdown_login' && ($('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').find('input').is(":focus") || $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').find('select').is(":focus") )){
        }else{
            $('#navigation_horiz ul li').removeClass('active');
            $('#navigation_horiz ul').next('.dropdown').delay(700).slideUp(500);
        }
    });

    $('#TabbedPanels1 .TabbedPanelsContentGroup').children().hide();
    $('#TabbedPanels1 .TabbedPanelsContentGroup').children(":eq(0)").show();

    $("#TabbedPanels1 .TabbedPanelsTabGroup li").live('click',function(){
        $(this).parent('ul').next('.TabbedPanelsContentGroup').children().hide();
        $(this).parent('ul').next('.TabbedPanelsContentGroup').children(":eq("+$(this).attr('tabindex')+")").show();
    }); 
    <!--

    //-->

});
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1");
```

Comment: It works for me in your Fiddle on IE10 and IE10 running under IE9 mode.

Comment: ok i checked in IE8 and 9 and not working , haven't upgraded to 10 yet, but assumed it would work there. Anyone have IE9v to check for a fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code hope it will help...

```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: added, but no luck , has to be issue with the script here http://jsfiddle.net/7aSDS/68/

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains lots of invalid HTML... Explorer hates invalid HTML.

See:

[http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2F7aSDS%2F53%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://jsfiddle.net/7aSDS/53/show/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

I'd fix them all, but you should really focus on fixing structure errors like these:

- End tag `div` seen, but there were open elements.
- Unclosed element module.
- Self-closing syntax (`/>`) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.
- Element module not allowed as child of element `div` in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Comment: thanks, but that wasn't the issue, i simplified the html and still will not open in IE9 New Demo here  http://jsfiddle.net/7aSDS/68/